# inserting into a table records from another table with a condition

Tags: sql

Let's say I have two tables t1 and t2.

- t1 has two integer cols col1 (primary) and col2
- t2 has two cols a foreign key of t1.col1 and t2.col2

I want to do the following

1. Retrieve only the records where t1.col2 is unique OR if t1.col2 is duplicate only those if t2.col2 is not null.
2. Insert the above records into another summary table, let's say t3

This is what I tried:

```
insert into t3 (col1,col2) 
    select col1, col2 
    from t1 
    where t.col1 in (select A.col1 from t1 as A 
                     group by 1 
                     having count(*) > 1
    union
    select col1, col2 
    from t1, t2 
    where t.col1 in (select A.col1 from t1 as A  
                     group by 1 
                     having count(*) > 1
      and t2.col2 is not null;
```

While the 'union qry' works on its own, the insert is not happening.

Any ideas or any other efficient way to achieve this please

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: Your subqueries **both** lack a closing parenthesis **`)`** after the  `having count(*) > 1` clause .... - and your second half of the `union` produces a cartesian cross join since you've specified two tables - comma-separated - in your `from` clause, and not **JOIN** condition between the two tables.....

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

You can select the records you want using:

```
select t1.*
from (select t1.*, count(*) over (partition by col2) as cnt
      from t1
     ) t1 
where cnt = 1 or
      exists (select 1 from t2.col1 = t1.col1 and t2.col2 is null);
```

The rest is just an `insert`.

Comment: thanks the issue is union qry is working on its own (I had accidentally left out the join condition), the issue is feeding this to insert, should there be any special 'treatment' needed whhen feeding a result set from a union to an INSERT?